How do I fix a VBA missing procedure error?
I'm trying to create  an Excel workbook where I can populate an array with digits 1-99.  The process I'm trying to create is to select a digit by clicking a button that would link to a VBA macro that copies the digit in a reference cell to the next cell I click.  Here's my VBA code:
Public Sub Number3(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        ' Specify your actual range and adjust the destination cell
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G15")) Is Nothing Then
            Dim clickedValue As Variant
            clickedValue = Target.Value
            Target.Offset(1, 0).Value = clickedValue
        End If
    End If
End Sub

I would like a) this to work and b) how to extend this so it will process up to 10 clicks after one button click
I;m getting this error when I click the button

I'd be happy to upload my workbook but I didn't see that as an option.
I tried making the routine Private
I tried adding a Cancel = True, suggested on line

The code you've posted won't cause that error - everything is within the procedure.  What code do you have above or below the Public Sub Number3(ByVal Target As Range) and End Sub lines?  It could also be in another module.

I don't have any other code.

Try this:
Public Sub Number3()
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        ' Specify your actual range and adjust the destination cell
        If Not Intersect(Selection, Range("G15")) Is Nothing Then
            Dim clickedValue As Variant
            clickedValue = Selection.Value
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Value = clickedValue
        End If
    End If
End Sub


How should that fix the compiler error?

@FunThomas That function works for me . Do you still have an error? What line is marked as faulty?

Thanks, I tried this code and did not get an error but I don't any result, i.e., after clicking the button and clicking in another cell, nothing happens.

Well If you select G15 and klick te button then it writes the same value in G16

The Sub itself isn't the cause for the error.
You get such error if you have statements outside of a Sub or Function. The only statements that are allowed outside are

Compiler Options (Option Explicit, Option Base 1)
Declare-Statement to declare references to external procedures
Const and Dim Statements to define global Constants and Variables
Comments

Likely you have a statement like this in your code:
Option Explicit

x = 3

Public Sub Number3(ByVal Target As Range)
(...)
End Sub

The statement x = 3 is not allowed and will throw the compiler error. Sometimes it happens that you want to add a comment at the top and forget the comment character.
To locate such an error, switch to the VBA editor and use Debug->Compile. This will show you the illegal statement.

Note that a routine that is called from a button cannot get a parameter, so the routine cannot be called at all. But you are not using the target parameter anyhow, just remove it.

Thanks, I don't have any other code at the moment. I tried the code below which does not use target.  See my comments there.
